# cross kernel 2D convolution with NAs in R

Tags: r, performance, image-processing, convolution

I have a matrix that has `NA`s. I aim to fill them in using the mean of the 4 neighboring values (a cross pattern). This is the "cross" pattern kernel:

```
kernel
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.00 0.25 0.00
[2,] 0.25 0.00 0.25
[3,] 0.00 0.25 0.00
```

Here's a code with a for loop. It works but I don't like it, it's not readable (even for me, it's really hard to follow what's happening). Additionally, I didn't benchmark, but I presume there might be a fastest way to do this.

```
mx <- matrix(rep(NA, 5^2), nrow = 5)
mx[3,3] <- 10
index <- which(is.na(mx), arr.ind = T)

for (i in 1:nrow(index)) {
  # if NA is at first row, use that one, otherwise we will subtract one
  bottom <- ifelse(index[i, 1] <= 1, index[i, 1], index[i, 1] - 1)
  # if NA is at the last row, use that one, otherwise we will add 1
  top <- ifelse(index[i, 1] >= nrow(mx), index[i, 1], index[i, 1] + 1)
  
  # if NA is at first column use that one, otherwise subtract one
  left <- ifelse(index[i, 2] <= 1, index[i, 2], index[i, 2] - 1)
  # if NA is at the end, use that one, otherwise add one
  right <- ifelse(index[i, 2] >= ncol(mx), index[i, 2], index[i, 2] + 1)
  # inplace substitution
  mx[index[i,1],index[i,2]] <- mean(c(
    mx[bottom, index[i, 2]],
    mx[top, index[i, 2]],
    mx[index[i, 1], right],
    mx[index[i, 1], left] ),
    na.rm=TRUE)

}
```

Expected result is

```
> mx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[2,]  NaN  NaN   10   10   10
[3,]  NaN   10   10   10   10
[4,]  NaN   10   10   10   10
[5,]  NaN   10   10   10   10
```

I tried using some image packages but couldn't find the exact thing I'm looking for. `OpenImageR::convolution` fails with `NA`s, `imager::inpaint()` does exactly what I want but doesn't allow me to provide my custom kernel.

```
# all of this reasoning is to convolve this filter
kernel <- matrix(c(0,1,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), nrow=3)
kernel <- kernel/4 # we need 1/4 to get the proper weights
# and use it to calculate the mean of the values
# then use the indices to fill the NAs on the original matrix
# not exactly working as I would like because of NAs
#OpenImageR::convolution(mx, kernel = kernel, mode = "same")
#imager::inpaint() does something similar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ifelse` is vectorized we can move that outside of `for` loop to get some improvements:

```
v3 <- function(x) {
  x2 <- x
  index <- which(is.na(x), arr.ind = T)
  i <- index[, 1]
  j <- index[, 2]
  bottom <- ifelse(i <= 1, i, i - 1)
  top <- ifelse(i >= nrow(x), i, i + 1)
  left <- ifelse(j <= 1, j, j - 1)
  right <- ifelse(j >= ncol(x), j, j + 1)
  
  for (z in 1:nrow(index)) {
    ii <- i[z]
    jj <- j[z]
    v <- c(x2[bottom[z], jj], x2[top[z], jj], x2[ii, right[z]], x2[ii, left[z]])
    x2[ii, jj] <- mean(v, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  x2
}
```

It could be all done without loops, but that gives different results, as in your approach new values are also used for further calculations:

```
v4 <- function(x) {
  x2 <- x
  index <- which(is.na(x), arr.ind = T)
  i <- index[, 1]
  j <- index[, 2]
  bottom <- ifelse(i <= 1, i, i - 1)
  top <- ifelse(i >= nrow(x), i, i + 1)
  left <- ifelse(j <= 1, j, j - 1)
  right <- ifelse(j >= ncol(x), j, j + 1)
  
  a <- c(x[cbind(bottom, j)],
         x[cbind(top, j)],
         x[cbind(i, right)],
         x[cbind(i, left)])
  a <- matrix(a, ncol = 4)
  r <- rowMeans(a, na.rm = T)
  x2[index] <- r
  x2
}
v4(mx)
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
# [2,]  NaN  NaN   10  NaN  NaN
# [3,]  NaN   10   10   10  NaN
# [4,]  NaN  NaN   10  NaN  NaN
# [5,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

... doesn't match. Benchmarks:

```
bench::mark(original(mx2), v3(mx2), v4(mx2), check = F)[, 1:5]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
# <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
# 1 original(mx2)  742.1us  766.1us     1299.      488B
# 2 v3(mx2)        114.2us  119.3us     8322.    4.07KB
# 3 v4(mx2)         46.1us   48.6us    20275.    9.46KB
```

p.s. `v3` results matches the original.

Comment: I like the speed a lot. One of the reasons I don't like my own version is that I think the readability is bad. I was hoping for something that would use the `apply` family. I wonder if this is not possible because, as you mention, my expected output uses new calculations to fill the adjacent places

Comment: @MatiasAndina Yes, I think because of that `for` loop is the only option. I would not say that the readability is so bad, I was able to understand the code :)